# Chip input in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

How to use material-ui-chip-input in react-admin ?

I tried to write such code, but as a result nothing is sent to the server.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import ChipInput from 'material-ui-chip-input';

const renderChipInput = ({ input, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
        <ChipInput {...input}/>

);
const Chip = () => <Field name="tags" component={renderChipInput} />
export default Chip;
```

Comment: Add some more code (the view in which you're using this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It work code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import ChipInput from 'material-ui-chip-input';

const renderChipInput = ({ input, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
        <ChipInput {...input}
                   value = { input.value || []}
                   onAdd={(addedChip) => {
                       let values = input.value || [];
                       values = values.slice();
                       values.push(addedChip);
                       input.onChange(values);
                   }}
                   onDelete={(deletedChip) => {
                       let values = input.value || [];
                       values = values.filter(v => v !== deletedChip);
                       input.onChange(values);
                   }}
                   onBlur={() => input.onBlur()}
        />
);
const Chip = () => <Field name="tags" component={renderChipInput} />
export default Chip;
```

Comment: Nice! Don't forget to mark your answer as "resolved".

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example implementation with `useField` and `react-admin@^3.0.0`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useInput } from 'react-admin';
import RawChipInput from 'material-ui-chip-input';

export function ChipInput(props) {
  const {
    input: { value, onChange, ...rest },
    meta: { touched, error },
    isRequired,
  } = useInput(props);

  if (value && !Array.isArray(value)) {
    throw new Error(
      `ChipInput requires an array value but received: ${JSON.stringify(
        value,
      )}`,
    );
  }

  return (
    <RawChipInput
      value={value || []}
      label={props.label}
      onAdd={(newChip) => onChange((value || []).concat(newChip))}
      onDelete={(deletedChip) =>
        onChange((value || []).filter((item) => item !== deletedChip))
      }
      error={!!(touched && error)}
      helperText={touched && error}
      required={isRequired}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
}
```

More info about custom inputs in official docs: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#the-useinput-hook